# Visual C++ Sending message across thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writting a small server application which has ServerSocket object waiting for and create connection socket.
Each connection has a SocketListener and a SocketSender for transfering data.

Each SocketListener is a separate thread. When a connection is disconnect by client, SocketListener send a message to ServerSocket notify that it is closing, so that ServerSocket can clear the handle for that connection from a list.

However, don't know why the message is not received by SocketListener thread. I have tried to narrow down the message filter, but no luck. Could someone help me with this.

```
DWORD ServerSocket::m_ThreadFunc() {
// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed\n");
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT_STR, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed\n");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed\n");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed\n");
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// allow listener thread to report back its state
MSG msg;
ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));


//force create message queue
PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER + 100, PM_NOREMOVE);

printf("Listing for clients on port %s \n", DEFAULT_PORT_STR);
while (listening) {
    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Client connected\n");

        sender = new SocketSender(ClientSocket);

        listener = new SocketListener(ClientSocket, this->m_threadId);
        printf("Listener created\n");

        listener->setSender(sender);
        listener->startThread();

        printf("Listener started\n");

        listenerList.push_back(listener);
        senderList.push_back(sender);

        printf("Listener list size: %d \n", listenerList.size());

        printf("Listener pushed to list\n");

        //delete socket data if listener close itself due to connection lost or disconnect.

    }
    else {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("accept failed\n");
        switch (error) {
        case 10093:
            listening = false;
            try {
                closesocket(ListenSocket);
            }
            catch (...) {}
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Check message queue for thread message\n");
    //check thread message queue
    //GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0); //this blocks untill a message is get.

    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER + 100, PM_REMOVE);



    if (msg.message == WM_USER + 1)
    {
        //ProcessCustomMessage(msg);
        m_deleteListener((SocketListener*)msg.wParam);
        printf("Recieved message from ThreadID: %d \n", msg.wParam);
    }
    printf("Recieved message from ThreadID: %d \n", msg.message);

    printf("Server socket complete 1 loop\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

```
DWORD SocketListener::m_ThreadFunc() {
listening = true;

rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;

printf("Start thread with ID: %d \n", this->m_threadId);
printf("Parent Thread ID: %d \n", this->_iParentID);


while (listening) {
    int iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        recvbuf[iResult - 1] = 0; // null terminate the string according to the length

        // The message spec indicates the XML will end in a "new line"
        // character which can be either a newline or caraiage feed
        // Search for either and replace with a NULL to terminate
        if (recvbuf[iResult - 2] == '\n' || recvbuf[iResult - 2] == '\r')
            recvbuf[iResult - 2] = 0;

        try { 
            doc.parse<0>(&recvbuf[0]);
            HandleXMLMessage(&doc);
        }

        catch (...) {}

    }
    else {      
        printf("Thread %d is being closed, sending signal to parent (%d)\n", this->m_threadId, this->_iParentID);


        if (PostThreadMessage(this->_iParentID, WM_APP + 1, NULL, NULL) == 0)
        {
            printf("Client cant send Message before closing the conn ! \n");
            printf("Last error %d", GetLastError());
        }
        else {
            printf("Client sent Closing Message successfully \n");
        }


        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        return 1;
    }
}

printf("Server terminate connection\n");

printf("Thread %d is closed, sending signal to parent (%d)\n", this->m_threadId,this->_iParentID);

PostThreadMessage(this->_iParentID, WM_USER + 1, (WPARAM)this->m_threadId, NULL);


return 0;
```

}

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

accept function is a blocking call, so it looks like after accepting first connection your loop gets stuck at

```
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
```

And does not check thread message queue until the next connection is made.

You also need to check the return result of PeekMessage to know whether message was actually peeked otherwise msg variable will contain garbage.

Comment: Well, but I can see that it accepts more than 1 connections, and still do all the task in the loop except the PeakMessage and everything after that. If i create 3 connections, then disconnect 1, then create 2 more, everything works fine, except the closing message, hence totally there are 5 connections in the lists.

Comment: As i mentioned above, you don't check result of PeekMessage. And you don't check the result of PostThreadMessage either. Also when you post WM_USER+1 message you pass this->m_threadId as WPARAM, but when you peek this message you cast WPARAM to SocketListener * which will most likely lead to crash. Well, i suggest you to make a simple threading program which will create main and some worker threads that call Sleep(random_delay) to emulate work and then notify main thread. This way you can keep your threading logic separated and ensure that it works properly without dealing with network stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Actually I did check PostThreadMessage error
`code` if (PostThreadMessage(this->_iParentID, WM_APP + 1, NULL, NULL) == 0)
        {
            printf("Client cant send Message before closing the conn ! \n");
            printf("Last error %d", GetLastError());
        }`code`

There is no error.
And you are right, I get the message parameter and cast to something else (SocketListener*). I will fix that and see if that is help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: thank you @dodo951 for your help. I figured out my problem.

Comment: Well, it is actually your answer @dodo951. Yesterday, i did not understand your answer about accept() function. Sorry, it was my bad. Your answer is CORRECT, but I can't vote for it as my reputation is low, i guess. I will delete my answer below, as it is originally yours